# Subsonic 3 ActiveRecord generation problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

I´m newer user in stack overflow and my english i´snt so good i hope you understand my trouble.

when I´m compiling my template this archives .cs it´s ok (Context, Structs), but in the ActiveRecord the code comes incomplete.

It seems that the system Break de compilation at line 5017 and not return any exceptions to me.

my code stops here:

> ```
> public static PagedList<Veiculoopcional>
> ```
>
> GetPaged(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
>   {
>               return GetRepo().GetPaged(pageIndex,
>   pageSize);
>
> ```
>     }
>
>     public string KeyName()
>     {
>         return "
> ```

i guess this probably a limit of transmition or problem with my table "VeiculoOpcional".. i don´t know.

Any way this the strcture of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `veiculoopcional` (
   `ID_Veiculo` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ID_Opcional` int(4) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Veiculo`,`ID_Opcional`),
   KEY `FK_veiculoopcional_Opcional` (`ID_Opcional`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_veiculoopcional_Opcional` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Opcional`) REFERENCES `opcional` (`ID_Opcional`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `FK_veiculoopcional_Veiculo` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Veiculo`) REFERENCES `veiculo` (`ID_Veiculo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Anybody had or passed by this same problem ? i don´t found any refference in net

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SubSonic does not support composite primary keys (i.e. multiple column primary keys).  Make the pair ('ID_Veiculo','ID_Opcional') unique, add a new column, and make the new column your primary key.

Comment: Thanks Spark! That Works for me Thanks, i just not make the Thirdy column with PK because it´s a low Table.

Regards